# Give Data of Birth column as Age in Telerik Report

Tags: sql, sql-server, telerik, telerik-mvc, telerik-reporting

using below query I'm getting

```
SELECT

        [tbl_HEI_student].[Gender], 
        [tbl_HEI_student].[Date_of_Birth],
        [tbl_HEI_student].[Programme_ID], 
        [tbl_hec_Programme].[ISCED_ID], 
        [tbl_hec_Programme].[Programme_ID] AS 'tbl_hec_ProgrammeProgramme_ID', 
        [tbl_hec_ISCED].[ISCED_ID] AS 'tbl_hec_ISCEDISCED_ID', 
        [tbl_hec_ISCED].[ISCED_Level]

    FROM (([tbl_HEI_student]
     FULL OUTER JOIN [tbl_hec_Programme]
     ON [tbl_HEI_student].[Programme_ID] = [tbl_hec_Programme].[Programme_ID])
     FULL OUTER JOIN [tbl_hec_ISCED]
     ON [tbl_hec_Programme].[ISCED_ID] = [tbl_hec_ISCED].[ISCED_ID])
    WHERE ([tbl_hec_Programme].[ISCED_ID]='5' or [tbl_hec_Programme].[ISCED_ID]='6' or [tbl_hec_Programme].[ISCED_ID]='7' or [tbl_hec_Programme].[ISCED_ID]='8')
```

this kind of report

[image: Fig:1]

But I want to calculate age and categorize .but I want to do this using Date_of_Birth field in above query to get exactly this kind of report

how to do this in query level

[image]

Comment: Are you using both MySQL and MS SQL Server here? (Don't tag products not involved...)

Comment: yes you're correct just edited !

Answer (score 0):

you can Get the age by using  `datdiff` function and then group by

`select DateDiff(YEAR,'1984-04-21',getdate())` for year

`select DateDiff(MONTH,'1991-01-21',getdate())/12` for Months

`select DateDiff(DAY,'1984-04-21',getdate())/365` for days

```
WITH ABC
AS (
    SELECT DateDiff(MONTH, '1984-04-21', getdate()) / 12 AS AGE
        ,'Arun' AS NAME

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DateDiff(MONTH, '1984-02-21', getdate()) / 12 AS AGE
        ,'Gorrv'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DateDiff(MONTH, '1985-05-21', getdate()) / 12 AS AGE
        ,'Gorrv'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DateDiff(MONTH, '1985-06-21', getdate()) / 12 AS AGE
        ,'Gorrv'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DateDiff(MONTH, '1985-07-21', getdate()) / 12 AS AGE
        ,'Gorrv'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DateDiff(MONTH, '1985-03-21', getdate()) / 12 AS AGE
        ,'Gorrv'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DateDiff(MONTH, '1990-01-21', getdate()) / 12 AS AGE
        ,'Manu'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DateDiff(MONTH, '1991-01-21', getdate()) / 12 AS AGE
        ,' Rishi'
    )
SELECT AGE
    ,Count(NAME)
FROM abc
GROUP BY Age
```

Comment: thanks for the reply , but your answer vary to row by row, 

in here I want write a query to

 `SELECT   [tbl_HEI_student].[Date_of_Birth] as Age,` portion